# How to undo a keystroke (VIM)

Tags: vim

Vim's undo system can become somewhat cumbersome when one accidently presses a key that...

- changes modes.
- performs multiple operations.

Is there a way to undo that takes vim back to the state *(cursor location, mode and text-buffer)* vim was in before the key was pressed?

---

To elaborate on this a little more, say I'm in insert mode and press `Return` or `o`,
with my current `.vimrc` will keep the current indentation. This is what I want - but it means undoing an accidental keypress is no longer a single action (in this case I have to press `Esc, u`).

Answer (score 4):

Vim's undo system is very powerful (with *undo branches* etc.), but it's still limited to *text changes*. In contrast, the *editor state* (current mode, buffer, etc.) isn't covered; any changes with regards to undo happen only when they are side effects of the undone text change (so, for example, when you undo a deletion, the cursor moves back to the formerly deleted range).

It's hard to imagine how an undo system with the features you describe would work, but I guess the additional "changes" would be rather confusing than helpful, so I don't think this is desirable.

If you're occasionally surprised by mode changes or unintended execution of mappings, try to improve your setup, e.g. via:

- clearly highlighting the current mode (plugins like *Airline* do this prominently in the statusline, including color changes)
- show partial mappings via `:set showcmd`
- increase `'timeoutlen'`, so that you have more time to type a (long) mapping
- restructure your mappings, so that they are easier to type, or prefer custom commands over mappings (avoiding the timeout issues)